# How to ensure an inequality graph updates its shading dynamically in JSXgraph?

Tags: javascript, attributes, jsxgraph

I am making a dynamic graph of an linear inequality. I want there to be two draggable points that dynamically change the inequality graph. I also want a button that toggles whether the line is dashed or solid, and another button that toggles the shading direction.

I'm essentially done, but I can't get the shading to switch sides when the button is pressed.

My current code can be found and run at https://jsfiddle.net/einstien311/kj7udbnh/11/ .

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
  boundingbox: [-12, 12, 12, -12],
  axis: true,
  grid: true
});


// Initialize points for default graph
var firstBluePoint = board.create('point', [1, -4], {
  name: '',
  snapToGrid: true,
  color: 'blue',
  highlightStrokeColor: 'blue',
  highlightFillColor: 'blue'
});

var secondBluePoint = board.create('point', [2, -2], {
  name: '',
  snapToGrid: true,
  color: 'blue',
  highlightStrokeColor: 'blue',
  highlightFillColor: 'blue'
});


// Create Lines 
var blueLine = board.create('line', [() => -1 * ((secondBluePoint.Y() - firstBluePoint.Y()) / (secondBluePoint.X() - firstBluePoint.X()) * (-firstBluePoint.X()) + firstBluePoint.Y()), () => -1 * ((secondBluePoint.Y() - firstBluePoint.Y()) / (secondBluePoint.X() - firstBluePoint.X())), 1], {
  name: '',
  color: 'blue',
  highlightStrokeColor: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 2.5,
  dash: 0,
  visible: true
});


// Create Inequalities Shaded Region
var blueInequality = board.create('inequality', [blueLine], {
  color: 'blue',
  fillOpacity: 0.18,
  strokeWidth: 0,
  inverse: true
})


// Blue Line Button
var toggleBlueLinePattern = board.create('button', [-11.5, -9.9, 'Change Blue Line', function() {
  if (blueLine.getAttribute('dash') == 0) {
    blueLine.setAttribute({
      dash: 3
    });
  } else {
    blueLine.setAttribute({
      dash: 0
    });;
  }
}]);


// Blue Shading Button
var toggleBlueShadeDirection = board.create('button', [-12, -11.1, 'Change Blue Shading', function() {
  if (blueInequality.getAttribute('inverse')) {
    blueInequality.setAttribute({
      inverse: false
    });
  } else {
    blueInequality.setAttribute({
      inverse: true
    });
  }
}]);


// Visualize whether the attribute truly changes
var blueInequalityInverseAttributeListener = board.create('point', [() => (blueInequality.getAttribute('inverse') ? 1 : 0), 0], {
  name: 'Blue Inequality Inverse Attribute Listener',
  color: 'green',
  highlightStrokeColor: 'green',
  highlightFillColor: 'green',
  visible: true
});
```

What I've tried so far to diagnose the issue:

I've made a point on the graph called "blueInequalityInverseAttributeListener" that dynamically shows the value of the inverse attribute of the inequality. When the button is pressed, the Listener Point toggle between 0 and 1, which (if I've done it correctly) indicates to me that the inequality's attribute truly does get updated as intended by the button.

Therefore, I can only conclude that although the attribute is updated, the change is not reflected on the graph. I'm not sure if there's some syntax I don't know or if there's some function I need to call to re-render the inequality. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Einstien311

P.S. I'm only a few months into JSXgraph, and that is my only experience with JavaScript, so my syntax might not be very elegant :/

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience, this is a bug in v1.6.2. Fortunately, it had been fixed a view weeks ago in the `develop` branch of JSXGraph. The upcoming version 1.7.0 will contain the bug fix.

Comment: @AlfredWassermann  I appreciate the help. On a similar note, It seems that the shading direction of the inequality is dependent on the order of the points in the line. For example, take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/einstien311/vtzx68wh/10/ . Initially, the inequality shades below, but if you drag the points to swap their locations, the inequality shades above.  I'm not sure if this is a feature or a bug, but I anticipated the inequality to always shade below if inverse:false.  Can you clarify if this is a feature or a bug? It's decently clunky for me to get it to work the way I wanted.

Comment: Your example with JSXGraph v1.7.0 is at https://jsfiddle.net/up0kjobg/. My first impression is that it is ok.